# How add CJuiDatePicker in JQRelcopy on Yii Framework

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii1.x, yii-events

I have a problem with CJuiDatePicker in the module JQRelcopy on Yii framework.

I use this module as I have a form with a datepicker field to be copied as many times as the user wishes.

The module works fine if I put a normal field (without datepicker), but as soon as I add the module CJuiDatePicker which is also a module of the Yii framework, I have a blank page appears. I followed the following tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/jqrelcopy/ explains the integration jqrelcopy in a form containing CJuiDatePickerm, which is exactly what I need.

I study the problem and I saw that it was when I Atoute the following line in the properties of my widget JQRelcopy the problem occurs:

> 'jsAfterNewId' => JQRelcopy::afterNewIdDatePicker($datePickerConfig),

in

> $this->widget('ext.jqrelcopy.JQRelcopy', array(
>
> ```
>   'id' => 'copylink',
>   'removeText' => 'remove',
>
>   //add the datapicker functionality to the cloned datepicker with the same options
>   'jsAfterNewId' => JQRelcopy::afterNewIdDatePicker($datePickerConfig),
> ```
>
> ));

I look in several forums and anywhere a person has had the same problem as me.

Comment: Do you not get any error messages? In the console?

Comment: No, i haven't got error messages. I just have got a blank page !

Comment: And in firebug/console (google chrome CTRL + SHIFT + J)?

Comment: I have got this :

<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>

so I think it must be a PHP error

Comment: Did you try to do that out of your project ? In a brain new clean project where only that piece of code is running. Maybe it is a conflict with another functionality.

Comment: Yes, I've tried but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could do this in the past, was ditching the CJuiDatePicker and using the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method of JQuery.

```
$('body').on('focus', '.idata', function(){
        jQuery(this).datepicker(
            jQuery.extend(
                {showMonthAfterYear:false},
                jQuery.datepicker.regional['pt-BR'],
                {'showAnim':'fold','dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'}
            )
        );
    });
```

Or, you can use live method...

Answer (score 0):

Just Import ext.jqrelcopy.JQRelcopy in your form file at the top

```
Yii::import('ext.jqrelcopy.JQRelcopy');
```

Your Problem be solved if any Issue let me know i will further assist.